# How do I update infos every x seconds with vanilla JS that I get with fetch()?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I have some information that I'm receiving with fetch() and the infos stay as how they were at the time of the call. The original json is updated every 10 seconds and I'd like to take advantage of that by updating the fetch every 10 seconds. How do I do that?

my code is:

```
   fetch('https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=my_key&ids=BTC,ETH,XRP&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1')
            .then(function (response) { return response.json(); })
            .then(function (data) { appendData(data); });
    
    
        function appendData(data) {
            document.getElementById('pikcs').src = data[2].logo_url;
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("ideir");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = data[i].id + " " + data[i].name + "<br> $" + data[i].price; div.style.paddingRight = "50px";
                var imzs = document.createElement("img");
                imzs.src = data[i].logo_url; imzs.style.height = "40px";
                
                mainContainer.appendChild(imzs);
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
```

Comment: I suggest you to separate `fetch` function from `setInterval` function.

Comment: In your `appendData` function, you create a new `mainContainer` everytime data are fetched, adding them to it. That's why data are added - and not simply updated. You should re-think that function. And I suggest you to use template literals to output fetched data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval()`

```
 const interval = setInterval(function() {
       fetch('https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=my_key&ids=BTC,ETH,XRP&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1')
            .then(function (response) { return response.json(); })
            .then(function (data) { appendData(data); });
     }, 1000); //1000 means 1 sec, 5000 means 5 seconds
```

Comment: should I wrap the whole thing in a function and call that or call just one thing from the code eg. return response() or something?

Comment: you can just add the `fetch` call between the setInterval Func like I updated the answer

Comment: I tried, but this adds the same thing multiple times to the divs

Comment: I see the problem that it is appending the info again, how do I overwrite the current one instead of adding more copies of it?

Comment: If you append the data, it will always add new fetched data with old one. 
for this will will have to replace the data and get full data in fetch call.I hope you can understand this.

Comment: if this answers your query for making call every sec, please take a sec to accept this as accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: it answers half of the question - repeating it every x seconds, but the other half of the question was not answered - how do I update the values - it makes sense that append has to change to something else, but the question also is that - how do I update the values (not add more every x seconds)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230183/discussion-between-m-shoaib-qureshi-and-bambadamm).